# Entity Framework and migration issue

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

this is my sample class

```
public class Contacts
{
    [Key]
    public int ContactID { get; set; }

    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public string Fax { get; set; }
    public bool IsDefault { get; set; }

    public int AddressID { get; set; }
    public virtual Addresses Customer { get; set; } 

}
```

in our database EF already create table for Contacts. i add one new field to contact class and that is `public bool IsDefault { get; set; }`

when i try to migrate like this way

```
Enable-Migrations
Add-Migration AddIsDefault
Update-Database -Verbose
```

then VS show new fields is added. the sql i got for that from package manager console like

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Contacts] ADD [IsDefault] [bit] NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Customers] ADD [Address1] [nvarchar](max)
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Customers] ADD [Address2] [nvarchar](max)
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Customers] ADD [Phone] [nvarchar](max)
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Customers] ADD [Fax] [nvarchar](max)
INSERT [dbo].[__MigrationHistory]([MigrationId], [ContextKey], [Model],  [ProductVersion])
VALUES (N'201609071306198_AddIsDefault', N'EFTest.TestDBContext',
```

i though new fields has been added but when i query contacts table then saw no new field has been added.

migration details

```
namespace EFTest.Migrations
{
    using System;
    using System.Data.Entity.Migrations;

    public partial class AddIsDefault : DbMigration
    {
        public override void Up()
        {
            AddColumn("dbo.Contacts", "IsDefault", c => c.Boolean(nullable: false));
            AddColumn("dbo.Customers", "Address1", c => c.String());
            AddColumn("dbo.Customers", "Address2", c => c.String());
            AddColumn("dbo.Customers", "Phone", c => c.String());
            AddColumn("dbo.Customers", "Fax", c => c.String());
        }

        public override void Down()
        {
            DropColumn("dbo.Customers", "Fax");
            DropColumn("dbo.Customers", "Phone");
            DropColumn("dbo.Customers", "Address2");
            DropColumn("dbo.Customers", "Address1");
            DropColumn("dbo.Contacts", "IsDefault");
        }
    }
}
```

i did not write any code for seed. is it the reason for which new field has not been added to my contacts table ?

please guide me why new field called IsDefault not being added to table event after migration command issuing ? thanks

### my updated post

```
public class TestDBContext : DbContext
    {
        public TestDBContext()
            : base("name=TestDBContext")
        {
        }

        public DbSet<Customer> Customer { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Addresses> Addresses { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Contacts> Contacts { get; set; }
    }
```

### connection string is in app.config file

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="TestDBContext" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\DB\TestDB.mdf;Integrated Security=True"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

### Issue solved

problem was at my end.

my connection string was looking like

EF migration do not understand the meaning of `DataDirectory path`

the moment i hard code the db file path like below connection then issue was solved.

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="TestDBContext" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=c:\users\user1\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\EFTest\EFTest\DB\TestDB.mdf;Integrated Security=True"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

Comment: No, seed not needed to add the column. If you check the __MigrationHistory table in the database is there a record for the 201609071306198_AddIsDefault migration in there?

Comment: can you share your `connection string` and the `DbContext` code ?

Comment: @SteveGreene i check __MigrationHistory and found no record for 201609071306198_AddIsDefault. only records is there for InitialCreate. just do not understand why new field is not getting added.

Comment: @Sampath i update my post like what u r looking for.

Comment: You're not pointing where you think. What project is selected in the console when you run the commands? Is this the project where the above connection string resides?

Comment: yes. issue solved. i will post here what was wrong at my end for which new field was not getting added to contacts table.

Comment: i update here how i solve this issue. thanks all for the time.

Comment: Actually EF does understand DataDirectory - it interprets it as App_Data by default for web apps so if you check that folder there is probably another database sitting there. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/smartclientdata/2005/08/26/working-with-local-databases/